# Rewriting $\prod_{i=1}^{n}\frac{x_i}{(1+x_i)^2}$ as $\frac{\prod_{i=1}^{n}x_i}{\prod_{i=1}^{n}(1+x_i)^2}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Can we rewrite

$$\prod_{i=1}^{n}\frac{x_i}{(1+x_i)^2}$$

as

$$\frac{\prod_{i=1}^{n}x_i}{\prod_{i=1}^{n}(1+x_i)^2}$$

?

Comment: Why you want to rewrite this product?

Comment: The product is commutative, hence you can rearrange a finite product in any way you like.

Comment: @aGer to find  minimal sufficient statistic for logistic distribution , i need to rewrite a product term .

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes you can because $\frac AB\times\frac CD=\frac{AC}{BD}$.